# Posso declarar um construtor nas classes filhas quando a classe mãe é abstrata e já tem um construtor?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor, classes-abstratas

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Se posso declarar um construtor em uma classe `abstract` e também nas classes filhas. E também como acessar os valores deles. Por exemplo:

```
abstract class Animal {
    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public funtion __construct($nome, $idade) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
    }
}
```

E na classe filha, que herda da classe `Animal`:

```
class Cachorro extends Animal {
    private $corPelo;

    public function __construct($corPelo) {
        $this->corPelo = $corPelo;
    }
}
```

E quando tento instanciar chamo a classe `Cachorro` instanciando os valores para `Animal`:

```
$dog = new Cachorro('belinha', 4, 'preto');
```

Porém, dessa forma não consigo acessar a `corPelo` da classe filha `Cachorro`, apenas os valores da classe mãe `Animal`.

Estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Já removeu o '' do $dog = new Cachorro(''belinha',4,'preto')? Seria 'belinha' e não ''belinha. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: digitei errado o código aqui no stackOverFlow. Mas mesmo estando assim 'belinha' (entre aspas) não funciona :/

Comment: mas no caso de eu usar um classe-filha para herdar a classe mãe abstrata, pode né ?

Comment: dai eu instancio a classe filho e acesso os atributos da classe mãe abstrata

Comment: Esquece, removi o comentário. Vi a instancia da classe errada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, pode, o construtor é justamente para inicializar propriedades essenciais da classe, portanto cada classe deverá ter seu próprio construtor.

Quando uma classe filha vai inicializar, ela precisa inicializar também a classe pai.

Para chamar o construtor da classe pai você usará o [`parent`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class Cachorro extends Animal {
    private $corPelo;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade, $corPelo) {
        parent::__construct($nome, $idade);
        $this->corPelo = $corPelo;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/ConstructorInheritance.php).

Se não chamar o construtor a inicialização da classe `Cachorro` ficará capenga já que faltará a inicialização da classe `Animal` que me parece ser essencial para o `Cachorro` estar em ordem.

Comment: nossa perfeito, deu certo aqui.

Muitooo obrigado :)

Comment: posso usar parent nas classes filho para alterar/adicionar qualquer propriedade dos métodos da classe mãe ou tem alguma restrição ?

Comment: As propriedades são aqueles está lá, você não pode adicionar ou remover propriedades de outra classe. Pelo menos não em condições normais (o PHP aceita fazer maluquices). Mas se você quer saber se consegue acessar propriedades da classe superior, pode desde que a visibilidade dela seja `protected`. Ou `public` mas aí todo mundo pode. Com `private` não dá dá.

Comment: ok, então parent é unicamente usado para o construtor ?

Comment: Não, pode usar sempre que for acessar qualquer membro a classe superior herdada.

Comment: Esplendido......