# Duvidas sobre classe abstract e método __construct?

Tags: php, classes, construtor

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
abstract class Weeks
{

  protected $year;
  protected $this_week;
  protected $last_week;

  /**
  * @param $date deverá ser no formato new DateTime().
  **/
  public function __construct($date)
  {
    $this->year = $date->format('Y');
    $this->this_week = $date->format('W');
    $this->last_week = ($date->sub(new DateInterval('P1W')))->format('W');
  }
}
```

Ai eu estendo ela dentro de outras classes por exemplo:

```
class Training_Load_Week extends Weeks
{

      private $trainingLoadThisWeek;

      /**
      * @param $training_load é um array multidimensional contendo todos os treinos separados por [ano][numero_da_semana](treinos)
      **/
      public function setTrainingLoadThisWeek($training_load)
      {
        $this->trainingLoadThisWeek = array_sum( $training_load[$this->year][$this->this_week] );
      }

      public function getTrainingLoadThisWeek()
      {
        return $this->trainingLoadThisWeek;
      }
}
```

---

```
$training_load_week = new Training_Load_Week($today);
$training_load_week->setTrainingLoadThisWeek($arr_tl);
```

E essa:

```
class Training_Load_Last_Week extends Weeks
{

      private $trainingLoadLastWeek;

      /**
      * @param $training_load é um array multidimensional contendo todos os treinos separados por [ano][numero_da_semana](treinos)
      **/
      public function setTrainingLoadLastWeek($training_load)
      {
        $this->trainingLoadLastWeek = array_sum( $training_load[$this->year][$this->last_week] );
      }

      public function getTrainingLoadLastWeek()
      {
        return $this->trainingLoadLastWeek;
      }
}
```

---

```
$training_load_last_week = new Training_Load_Last_Week($today);
$training_load_last_week->setTrainingLoadLastWeek($arr_tl);
```

O que tá acontecendo é o seguinte, a data não está recomeçando sempre na data informada na variável `$today`

Ela continua de onde parou no uso da primeiro classe, por exemplo, era para ser semana 34 para `$this->week` e semana 33 para `$this->last_week`

Mas quando chamo a segunda classe, ele não usa esses mesmos valores, ele continua de onde parou no usa da classe anterior, isto é, retorna os valores `$this->week` como 33 e `$this->last_week` como 32, mas deveria ser 34 e 33 novamente.

Não to entendo por que.

Comment: porque você precisa chamar o construtor da classe abstrata !!! e ser explicito nessa declaração.

Comment: Já tem uma explicação sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45297/posso-declarar-um-construtor-nas-classes-filhas-quando-a-classe-m%C3%A3e-%C3%A9-abstrata-e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo é com o argumento `$date` do constructor `public function __construct($date)`. Mesmo que o padrão php para passagem de argumentos seja a passagem por valor para os tipos primitivos, para tipos complexos como o objeto `DateTime` essa passagem de argumentos é feita por referencia implicando que qualquer alteração no argumento `$date` será efetivamente realizada em sua referência que é o seu objeto `$today = new DateTime();`.

Para fazer a constatação que é um problema com uma modificação não pretendida no objeto referenciado eu alterei o constructor da classe `Week` de forma a exibir o valores de entrada e de saída de `$date`:

```
abstract class Weeks
{

  // Tornei os membros $year, $this_week e $last_week públicos somente para facilitar meus testes
  public $year;
  public $this_week;
  public $last_week;

  /**
  * @param $date deverá ser no formato new DateTime().
  **/
  public function __construct($date)
  {
    // Aqui mede o valor de entrada do argumento $date
    print_r("valor de entrada = ". $date->format('W'). "\n");

    $this->year = $date->format('Y');
    $this->this_week = $date->format('W');
    $this->last_week = ($date->sub(new DateInterval('P1W')))->format('W');

    // Aqui mede o valor de saída do argumento $date após o código
    print_r("valor de saída = ". $date->format('W'). "\n");
  }
}
```

Então eu fiz quatro testes:

```
echo "$training_load_week";
$training_load_week = new Training_Load_Week($today);
echo "$training_load_week1";
$training_load_week1 = new Training_Load_Week($today);
echo "$training_load_last_week";
$training_load_last_week = new Training_Load_Last_Week($today);
echo "$training_load_last_week1";
$training_load_last_week1 = new Training_Load_Last_Week($today);
```

E resultado foi:

```
$training_load_week
valor de entrada = 34
valor de saída = 33

$training_load_week1
valor de entrada = 33
valor de saída = 32

$training_load_last_week
valor de entrada = 32
valor de saída = 31

$training_load_last_week1
valor de entrada = 31
valor de saída = 30
```

Ok isso confirma a modificação indesejada na referência. Agora o próximo passo é identificar o que está causando a modificação.

Analisando a documentação das funções usada no constructor eu encontrei a causa na linha...

```
$this->last_week = ($date->sub(new DateInterval('P1W')))->format('W');
```

...mais precisamente na no método [`$date->sub`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.sub.php). Esse método não só retorna a data modificada como efetivamente modifica o objeto que a evocar no caso o objeto `$today` que é referenciado por `$date` dentro do constructor.
   Para fazer o reparo desse código é simples basta fazer um clone do argumento `$date`.

```
abstract class Weeks
{
  // Tornei os membros $year, $this_week e $last_week públicos somente para facilitar meus testes
  public $year;
  public $this_week;
  public $last_week;

  /**
  * @param $date deverá ser no formato new DateTime().
  **/
  public function __construct($date)
  {
    // Está qui o reparo do código
    $date = clone $date;

    print_r("valor de entrada = ". $date->format('W'). "\n");

    $this->year = $date->format('Y');
    $this->this_week = $date->format('W');
    $this->last_week = ($date->sub(new DateInterval('P1W')))->format('W');

    print_r("valor de saída = ". $date->format('W'). "\n");
  }
}
```

Refiz os mesmos testes e o resultado foi:

```
$training_load_week
valor de entrada = 34
valor de saída = 33

$training_load_week1
valor de entrada = 34
valor de saída = 33

$training_load_last_week
valor de entrada = 34
valor de saída = 33

$training_load_last_week1
valor de entrada = 34
valor de saída = 33
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por toda explicação.
Não iria descobrir isso nunca, sou aprendiz no assunto ainda, estudo php para objetivos pessoais.